# Trying to make a simple app with addition of variables, having some problems

Tags: java, android, eclipse, timepicker, addition

I have a timePicker with a 24h format and I want to take the results, put them into variables, using the variables in addition and then display them in a textView. Eclipse isn't giving me and syntax errors but when I run the app, it crashes when I start "DisplayMessageActivity.java".

Here is the code:

```
package com.example.sleepytime;

import android.annotation.SuppressLint;
import android.app.Activity;
import android.os.Bundle;
import android.view.View;
import android.widget.Button;
import android.widget.TextView;
import android.widget.TimePicker;

@SuppressLint("NewApi")
public class DisplayMessageActivity extends Activity {

 TimePicker timepicker;
 public int hour1 = timepicker.getCurrentHour();
 public int min1 = timepicker.getCurrentMinute();


@SuppressLint("NewApi")
@Override
protected void onCreate(Bundle savedInstanceState) {
    super.onCreate(savedInstanceState);
    setContentView(R.layout.activity_display_message);
    // Show the Up button in the action bar. 
    getActionBar().setDisplayHomeAsUpEnabled(true);

    timepicker = (TimePicker) findViewById(R.id.timePicker1);
    timepicker.setIs24HourView(true);

    Button mButton = (Button) findViewById(R.id.button1);
    mButton.setOnClickListener(new View.OnClickListener() { 
        public void onClick(View printIt) {
        final TextView mTextView = (TextView) findViewById(R.id.print);
        mTextView.setText(hour1 + min1);
}   

});
```

}

}

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Here

```
public int hour1 = timepicker.getCurrentHour();
public int min1 = timepicker.getCurrentMinute();
```

`timepicker` is `null`. You need to put it in `onCreate()` like here

```
protected void onCreate(Bundle savedInstanceState) {
    super.onCreate(savedInstanceState);
    setContentView(R.layout.activity_display_message);
    // Show the Up button in the action bar. 
    getActionBar().setDisplayHomeAsUpEnabled(true);

timepicker = (TimePicker) findViewById(R.id.timePicker1);
timepicker.setIs24HourView(true);
hour1 = timepicker.getCurrentHour();
min1 = timepicker.getCurrentMinute();
```

and change

```
public int hour1 = timepicker.getCurrentHour();
public int min1 = timepicker.getCurrentMinute();
```

to

```
public int hour1;
public int min1;
```

that is the first problem I see. There could be more but that will keep you from going any further.

```
 mButton.setOnClickListener(new View.OnClickListener() { 
    public void onClick(View printIt) {
    final TextView mTextView = (TextView) findViewById(R.id.print);
    String hourString = String.valueOf(hour);
    String minString = String.valueOf(minute);
    mTextView.setText(hourString + minString);
```

Comment: Thanks a lot! 

I'm not crashing at that spot anymore. My problem now is that the app crashes when I click "button1". What I want to happen (in the end) is that the user enter a time they want to wake up. The Application then uses a couple of formulas (that I have ready, I think) and give the user three alternative times that are recommended to fall asleep at.

Any suggestions?

Comment: You're welcome! You are probably crashing because you are trying to call `setText()` with `int`s. Convert each to a `String` with `String.valueOf(hour1);` then set that variable in the `setText()` You can do it inside `setText()` but it won't be as clean. Good luck to you!

Comment: Sorry, but I'm very new to this. How do I use String.valueOf(); correctly? Where do I put it?

Comment: No, problem. I have edited my answer. That just gets the `String` value of the `int`s. Something like that should work

Comment: And by the way. I have some mathematics I want to use the int's from the timePicker for. I basically want to take the timePicker value and perform a series of calculations. Where would I put these calculations in the code?

Comment: You could create a function to do the calculations that accept two `int` `params` and send the `int` values to that function when you click on your `Button`

Comment: Thanks man! I've solved all of the problems now but I still have one more question. How do I change the theme of my application? I've tried writing `android:theme="@Style/Theme.Holo"`inside of <application> in the manifest, but eclipse is just giving me red squiggly lines. Any ideas on how to solve it? :)

Comment: Check the error log and see what it says. Also, what version are you targeting and what is minVersion? Oh, and I think you need `style` instead of `Style` lowercase "s"

Answer (score 0):

```
TimePicker timepicker;
 public int hour1 = timepicker.getCurrentHour();
 public int min1 = timepicker.getCurrentMinute();
```

You can not do this, it will give you null pointer exception, do it like this

```
timepicker = (TimePicker) findViewById(R.id.timePicker1);
timepicker.setIs24HourView(true);
hour1 = timepicker.getCurrentHour();
min1 = timepicker.getCurrentMinute();
```

Plus your current code will break when run on api lower than 3.0.place a check on 
 getActionBar().setDisplayHomeAsUpEnabled(true);

or change the minimum sdk to 3.0 if you don't want to support versions prior to honeycomb